# Group and User Mapping

Tags: 2013, user-management, user-rights

In SDL Tridion 2011 the mapping of a user with a group (or vice versa) in CME can be done in two ways - Either you can select open a User and add it to a group from the Members tab or alternatively you can select open a Group and add the user to it from the Members tab.

However, SDL Tridion 2013, I observed that you can add a User to the Group but you can not Open a group and add user to it.

Just want to know if this is desired behaviour in 2013 version or I am missing something.

Also, if this is desired behaviour, is there some rationale behind it that I am not able visualize (except the load time may be too high in case AD (or LDAP) contains huge number of Users)

Can someone share their experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed the current behavior and was surprised enough to [post about it](http://www.createandbreak.net/2014/05/the-difference-between-tridion-designs.html). But I didn't realize any changes and just assumed I was mistaken before that you could add members *from within a group*.

I'm actually seeing the same behavior from 2013 SP1 and 2011 SP1, so any changes aren't specific to 2013. Are your differences for 2011 GA and earlier?

So for 2011 SP1 and up I'm seeing for new groups and when editing an existing group:

- In `Member of` tab, I can add this group to another group
- In `Members` tab, I can see existing groups and edit, but not add "subgroups" here

The 2013 docs confirm the behavior you're seeing on [Tridion 2013 SP1](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-988BA34D-0627-4122-9410-FB3BD3427A04) and [GA](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/task_9CF31DAE5EFA4D31A56A89A2912691CE). I can't find 2011 documentation equivalent except for [making a new group](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_05_2DDAFF2CF95E4430AA0F27AD7A91B5F8).

We still have the same ability to relate groups and subgroups. I haven't heard of any rationale for changes, but your Active Directory suspicion might be right. The [Tridion PowerTools has an extension to help adding users](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/AddUser) from an AD/LDAP setup with a large number of users. But I'd double-check with Support to be sure if you really need this functionality.

Comment: I think this has always been the case.

Comment: I have experienced with SDL Tridion 2011 GA and 2009, Will check about 2011 SP1 and update. I would probably share some screenshots as well if possible :)
By the way, nice post on your blog :)